# Wordpress - Three custom posts with the same slug

Tags: wordpress

I have three posts that have the same title and address, if I am logged in it displays my posts at all, but it logs out can not see them and shows me 404 if we can somehow read these posts?

i read post with this:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
            get_template_part('templates/content', 'single');
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your posts are private posts. Just edit a post from them and check at the right side of your content editor. There are few options, make this post public and then click on update.

Now check, your issue got resolved.

Go through this article for more info : http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-visibility